# AM I on the right path

Tags: oracle

I'm taking a database intro master's class.  We are working on SQL.  The professor likes to be ambiguous with certain explains.

Here's my question.  Certain questions we are required to find out the opposite of a query something like if a supplier ships parts that are red and blue what colors don't the ship.

here is how I figured out a solution

```
SELECT distinct PARTS.COLOR
FROM PARTS, SHIPMENTS
WHERE PARTS.COLOR NOT IN(
  SELECT distinct PARTS.COLOR
  FROM SHIPMENTS, PARTS
  WHERE PARTS.PARTNO  IN(
    SELECT distinct SHIPMENTS.PARTNO
    FROM SHIPMENTS
    WHERE SHIPMENTS.SUPPLIERNO='S1'))
AND SHIPMENTS.PARTNO = PARTS.PARTNO;
```

What I was wondering is, is this best approach to this question.  This works but I'm not sure it is how it should be done.

I should also mention he does not want us to use all available operations.  He did not show us JOIN, EXISTS,

he showed us SELECT, IN, ALL/ANY, Aggregates so MAX, MIN, SUM, GROUP BY, and HAVING

Thanks

Comment: It can be done with `group by` and `having`

Comment: I thought about that but was having trouble with the syntax.  In particular i didn't know that when using group you can't reference the table name.

Comment: Um select * From Table1,Table2 is a join. Would need the table schemas, or a sqlfiddle to really help you with this. Though anyone sane would be using joins anyway...

Comment: Not sure why but he wanted us to avoid joins and cartesian products We were not permitted to SELECT * either.

Answer (score 0):

If you learn now to use "EXPLAIN PLAN" to view the query plan, you'll find that Oracle often uses the same execution plan for "WHERE .. IN()" and "WHERE EXISTS". Depending on if there are indexes on the columns, it comes down to several aspects, mainly if you are using statistics gathering, Oracle will look at the number of rows for each table / index and decide which is the best way to execute it. So unless you find that IN() vs EXISTS() runs drastically differently than each other, just use whichever one makes most sense to you at the time, but always check the execution plan.

As far as your question, since you are prohibited from using joins or exists, I see nothing wrong with your solution.

The easy options I can come up with to simplify either use a join or an exists. You could do it with group and outer join, probably, but I see no point.

Without the restrictions, I could simplify it down to:

```
 SELECT distinct P.COLOR
   FROM PARTS P WHERE NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT 1 FROM SHIPMENTS S WHERE S.PARTNO = P.PARTNO AND S.SUPPLIERNO = 'S1')
```

though I am not certain about your schema, and where color is. I assumed a part has a distinct color. If not, this is not adequate and you'd need to correlate the subquery on color, not partno.

Comment: Thanks unfortunately INNER JOIN and EXISTS were two of the commands we were not permitted to use.  But I will try it this way in the future

Comment: @user3786519 I added a simpler option for you to learn from. Note I changed the column returned from the subquery to PARTNO, which allows you to use a single table in the subquery.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why but when I tried something similar it would give me all the parts.  I should have mentioned that different parts have the same color as in red, blue, and green.  Not sure if this matters.

Comment: Just one question in the previous examples why did you put 1 in the nested select statement   Thanks Again

Comment: Because all you care about in the exists is whether there is a result, not what the value is. WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T) is a convenient idiom. Just like COUNT(1). But you can also use a column name, or rowid, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is:   "if a supplier ships parts that are red and blue what colors don't they ship."

Interesting question.  I think the easiest method uses analytic functions, which you probably haven't covered:

```
select sp.supplierno, color, count(*)
from (select s.*, p.color
             max(case when p.color = 'red' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by partno) as HasRed,
             max(case when p.color = 'blue' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by partno) as HasBlue
      from shipments s join
           parts p
           on s.partno = p.partno
     ) sp
where hasRed > 0 and hasBlue > 0
group by sp.supplierno, color;
```

Comment: Does this use analytic functions?

Comment: @Ben . . . It should have and it did in my head.  Now the query even includes the analytic functions.